# don't stop mapping on not found

Tags: vim, macros

There is a important part of vim mapping:

`:map <C-j>r f{^`

I noticed, that when the `{` character is not found in the line, then the rest of the mapping is not executed.

Is there a way, how to force the mapping to continue even though the search character is not found? (In this case execute the return to the beginning of the file)

Comment: 1st, this is not macro, it is a mapping. can you paste the complete map cmd so that we can see what do you want to do? now you just want to move to `{` then go to the 1st non-blank, which makes no sense.

Comment: It makes no sense but it still behaves as he describes which seems strange to me.

Comment: @Kent thanks for correcting my terminology, changed to `mapping`. Well I just posted the relevant part of `mapping`, I think it's answerable without knowing the context. I don't want to explain it here, because I tried to boil down the question to the essence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Vim aborts on an error in a mapping. You can use `:silent! normal! ...` to continue regardless of errors. With a sequence of `:normal!` commands, you can even check (e.g. whether the cursor moved) and react to it. Sketch:

```
:map <C-j>r :exe 'normal! maf{'<Bar>if getpos("'a") == getpos(".")<Bar>echo "no move"<Bar>endif<CR>
```

Note that this doesn't scale well. You're better of moving the commands into a `:function`.

[Also, you should probably use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

The literal answer to this question would be:

`:map <C-j>r :silent! exe "normal f{^"<CR>`

Comment: Thanks, I actually needed to play with it for a while till I found the actual solution, so I included it in the answer.